# write error disk full in EC2 Machine

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, unix, amazon-ec2, unzip

I have my EC2 linux instance where some softwares are installed.
I downloaded a new zip and was trying to unzip it.

I got this error   write error (disk full?).  Continue? (y/n/^C) n

The zip is not corrupted and I can unzip it from other instances.

I change instance type from small to medium and then large.Nothing worked.

I ran df -h .

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         16G   56K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1      9.8G  9.7G     0 100% /
```

I think /dev/xvda1 is culprit. How can i increase the size of this?
What is this /dev/xvda1

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Makes sense.How can i move it to the other forum?

Comment: You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. It also resets the question's score. For whatever reasons, the Stack Exchange network does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a matter of instance type. You must change the volume (EBS) size.

1. Go to console and select the EBS of that instance , click action dropdown menu , then click modify volume  ( A form will appear with the current volume size, increase it )

[image]

[image]

2. Try to remove some kilobytes to be able to run (3). `rm -rf /tmp/*` for example.
3. Grow/Expand your filesystem :

   ```
   sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1
   sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1
   ```

NOTES :

- check Step(1) by `lsblk` command and check step (3 ) by `df -h`
- Scale down your instance before receiving a huge billing the end of month  ( Let it small as it was )

Comment: What is the third step for?

sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1
sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1

Comment: Step 1 will increase the size of your volume. But that does not increase the size of the filesystem sitting on the volume. Step 3 will make the filesystem expand to fill the volume.

Comment: sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1     

Is it exactly like this?  With space between xvda and 1 ?
And the second one?

Comment: Yup @MattHouser.  And he can check Step(1) by `lsblk` command and check step 3 by `df -h`

Comment: Yes Yes @Jocket with space .DON't modify any thing. We just copy/paste it from our runbook.

Comment: That worked i guess..
I changed the instance type to large.Can i change it back to small?

Comment: yes you can scale down, check my notes .. However, be careful when you increase EBS volume as you can only increase in the furture (no decrease) .

Comment: Sure.Thanks..I am trying it

Comment: Don't worry. It will work :)